# How to register and validate products keys using api with php?

Tags: php, validation, licensing, bluesnap

I created a module which I'm going to encrypt using ioncube. I'll use plimus to generate and validate product keys using http calls. plimus says, "there are 2 steps to this process":

1. register license by calling

   ```
   https://www.plimus.com/jsp/validateKey.jsp?action=REGISTER&productId=582710&key=XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX[&uniqueMachineId=YYYYYYY]
   ```
2. validating license by calling

   ```
   https://www.plimus.com/jsp/validateKey.jsp?action=VALIDATE&productId=582710&key=XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX[&uniqueMachineId=YYYYYYY]
   ```

The key will be sent to the user via email. I just need a php code sample to do this,
and also I'll need a check license code to add to my module.

Comment: Can you show us what code you have so far, and what your specific problem with that code is?

Comment: all my modules made in php .. I created modules for defferent kinds of software

Comment: Hm, perhaps I did not phrase that correctly.  Let me try again: What code do you already have to perform the HTTP requests and send the user mail, as you have described here?  We can't help you solve this problem without knowing where your code is malfunctioning.  :)

Comment: sorry for my mistake .. I create a modules for programes like whmcs and hostbill and so and so .. the progress plimus will send an email to the buyer after he paid includes the key .. so I myself don't perform any https to send an email .. but if you want me I can send a file of one module if you want to have alook .. or just I need a sample code to do those 2 steps ..

Comment: So, if you don't need sample code to call those two URLs, and you don't need sample code on how to send a mail, I'm really confused on *what specifically you are asking for*.

Comment: thanks again for your pation and sorry for my little english .. " I need a sample code of how to call those two urls I didn't say anything els .. again I need a php sample code

Comment: You are aware that plimus has a [rather questionable](http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/home.plimus.com) reputation? I note that only because of your examples, and many reports of phishing (for the sake of community goodness).

Comment: in fact I'm who will treat plimus not my clients .. all I'm going to do to use plimus to validate my license and if you have another trust solution to sell my license please tell me .. but my quistion is still how can I perform those 2 steps above using php , that what am i asking about .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

While PHP can make it very straightforward to make HTTP requests, setting it up correctly can be kind of a pain.  Your best bet is going to be using a third party library to manage the complexity so you don't have to set a thousand curl options or deal with how poorly the streams interface deals with HTTP codes that aren't 200.

[PEAR's HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) is a good starting point.  It's available under the BSD license, which means that you can bundle it with your own proprietary code without licensing issues.  Here is an extremely basic example that should work for you.  First, let's gather information about the actual request.

```
$endpoint_url = 'https://www.plimus.com/jsp/validateKey.jsp';
$params = array(
    'action' => 'REGISTER',
    'productId' = '582710',
    'key' => 'XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'
);
```

If you have a `uniqueMachineId`, you can add that to the array as well.

Now we'll build the request object.

```
$request = new HTTP_Request2($endpoint_url);
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::GET);
$request->getUrl()->setQueryVariables($params);
```

If you need to build a POST instead of a GET, [see the "Request Body" section in the docs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.request.php).  So, we've set the request up, let's actually execute it.

```
$response = $request->send();
$http_code = $request->getStatus();
$body_of_document = $response->getBody();
```

Tada.  Do whatever you need to do based on the resulting HTTP response code or the document body.

You can repeat this process for the other request as well, just changing the `$params` array and `$endpoint_url` as needed.

You should probably [read this manual section on the adapter options](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.adapters.php) as well.  The default configuration is very likely to work well for you, but you may need to request the curl adapter instead of the socket adapter.

As I mentioned, this isn't the only choice.  I'm a fan of [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.html), also available under a BSD license.  If you're feeling masochistic, you can also [use the curl extension directly](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and if you're entirely bat-guano insane, you can use my favorite thing in the world, [streams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)!

But seriously, HTTP_Request2 should do the job for you.